# Gnome Boxes: Ubuntu host crashed, Windows guest not restarting

Tags: gnome, virtualization

I'm running Gnome Boxes 40.3 on Ubuntu 21.10.  I'm searching online for an appropriate forum to ask this question.  The Gnome Boxes docs are not covering my problem and I haven't yet found a forum run by Red Hat.

Ubuntu froze on me when I was running Gnome Boxes with a Windows 10 guest.  I had to use the system's manual reset button.  I rebooted and started Gnome Boxes again.  I need to recover a file.  When I click the guest to start it, the progress icon spins forever and the guest never boots.

Please advise, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat unsatisfactory answer to my own question.  A **second** reboot of my Ubuntu host allowed me to start the Win10 guest.  I don't know why.  I like to understand what I'm doing, rather than guess blindly.